# Trying to get specific info from 10ish cells using API/json/google sheets

Tags: json, api, google-sheets

I'm totally new to this stuff. Never even heard of json/api/etc three days ago. Basically, I'm using the google sheets formula "=ImportJSON("https://universalis.app/api/Primal/7024")" to import data. However, there's almost 4000 cells worth of data in there and I only want about 10-20 cells worth of that. How can I narrow down what data it sends? [These are the only cells I want info from D2-D12.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9l9h.png) I assume I can adjust the formula after if I want, say, D2-D22 instead.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ImportJSON` is from [this](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON), how about the following modified formula?

#### Modified formula:

```
=QUERY(ImportJSON("https://universalis.app/api/Primal/7024"),"SELECT Col4 LIMIT 21 LABEL Col4 ''")
```

and

```
=QUERY(ImportJSON("https://universalis.app/api/Primal/7024","/listings/pricePerUnit","noHeaders"),"SELECT * LIMIT 21")
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how people are so smart. Thank you SO SO SO very much. I really appreciate this.

Comment: @Jessica Hunter Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hello, @Tanaike. I hope I'm okay to add on to this comment to ask for more help. Using the formula you gave me, I was able to get it work PERFECTLY, however, it's not updating automatically. I've seen a couple ways to do it that I've tried, but I think the QUERY in front is throwing the whole thing off? Do you, perhaps, know of a way to get the data to refresh without user input? Thanks.

Comment: @Jessica Hunter I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?